# how to get number of possible public keys in RSA

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to calculate the number of possible public keys.

The tuple for the public key is defined as: $Key_{Publ} = (n,a)$

So: 
Let $p:=83$ and $q:=163$

$n= p \cdot q = 83 \cdot 163 = 13529$

$\phi(n) = (p -1 )(q - 1) =(83 - 1)(163 - 1) = 13284$

**Question**: How is it possible to calculate the number of possible $a$'s in $\gcd(a , \phi(n))$ with $a \in [1, \phi(n)]$ ? 
So I will be able to calculate the possibilities with $n \cdot a$?

I have two possible ways to calculate $\phi(n):$
$$\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$$
$$\phi(n)=\prod_{p \in \mathbb P}(p^{v_p(n)-1}(p-1))$$

I appreciate every hint.

Comment: I don't understand the **Question**. Can you either clarify or check you have set it down correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

$\phi(\phi(n)) $ is the  number  of possible keys

Comment: can you show an example how you would calculate that with the numbers $p:=83$ and $q=163$, please?

Comment: i believe in  your exercise there is a Form  how  to  calculate  $\phi(n)$

Comment: and then ? $phi(13284)=?$ That is not clear to me

Comment: 13284 = $ 2^{2} 3^{4} 41 $

Comment: my exercise gives $4320$ as a solution. How can I achive that? Sorry, I need some help to understand..

Comment: in the beginning of this  question   , does the Exercies gives you  how to calculate $ \phi(n)$ ?  if yes can you  write it  down

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry for that. I have updated my question

Comment: exactly , now that you  have  13428 = $ 2^{2} 3^{4} 41 $
you  can now find  $\phi(13428)$ =$ 2^{(2-1)}*(2-1)*3^{(4-1)}*(3-1)*41^{(1-1)}*(41-1) = 2*3^{3}*2*40 = 4320$

Comment: p is Prime number  so in our care  is  2 or 3 or 41 
$v_{p}(n) $ is like $v_{2}(13284) =2$ and $v_{3}(13284) =4$ and $v_{41}(13284)=1$